# Why is my apache throwing error "Error : Apache Shutdown Unexpectedly"?

Tags: apache

Heres the error code when I try to start apache[image]

All the logs turn out empty with nothing in them. What I tried to do :

- I changed the ports and made sure that no application was using them
- Disabled localhost to see if it made a difference
- Changed the main port and ssl port
  (Heres my httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf files if you need them)
  httpd.conf : https://textdoc.co/0GDsHAyLiNQWMlhc
  httpd-ssl.conf : https://newtextdocument.com/df9b7be1de

and heres my active connections
https://www.writeurl.com/text/h4ifpwmg2nf6ng0c342u/vkrrqy2m6xu362gfqmfu
Any idea as to whats going wrong ? All other services (such as SQL) are running

EDIT : I tried running it in the CLI using `php -S localhost:9210 -t cf-restaurant-online-master` but it returned this error :

```
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Filename: C:\php\cf-restaurant-online-master\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php
```

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: The error log file of an apache http server is _never_ empty. Take another look please, directly at the log file. Do not rely on some fancy GUI on top of things, they are often more in the way that a help.

Comment: @arkascha I did I went directly through the file using file explorer there was nothing in there

Comment: How did you try to start the http server? Start it on CLI to see what happens exactly.

Comment: And also, could you please say which path the error log file has you checked?

Comment: @arkascha d:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log

Comment: @arkascha I used the command php -S localhost:9210 -t examplefolder to run it on the cli

Comment: That command has absolutely nothing to do with the apache http server. That starts a small standalone http server embedded in the php engine.